# Add record with random numbers (macro or VBA) in Access 2016

Tags: vba, ms-access

Nowhere seems to be a solution for this problem.

I have a table with 91 columns. The first column is a unique number that I will provide. The following 90 cells have to be filled with random numbers between 1 and 99. Each number may only be used once in this record.

I can connect the database to a MSSQL database and add rows to the table with a very simple Python script. Access will then import these added rows. But this is time consuming and not very user friendly.

I think it is possible to do all of this in Access (without the need for an external database or script) but I can't find anything on this subject.

Help is very welcome, thank you.

Comment: How are you connecting to the MSSQL database from the Python script, that you can't also connect directly to the Access database?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two possibilities:

- You could write a VBA function that returns a random number between 1 and 99, while keeping track of the previous numbers returned for a given row (via [module-level variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32045144)). There'll have to be some way of indicating a move to the next row -- either a magic value, or the function should have an optional parameter. You could then use this function as part of an SQL statement, and carry out bulk INSERTs with it.
- You could INSERT the record, and then fill them after the INSERT

  - either with a recordset (DAO or ADO)
  - or with an SQL statement with populated values into the string of the SQL statement
  - or with an SQL statement and query parameters

Answer (score 0):

Create the random number, place it in your field.  On subsequent passes, loop through all filled fields (I.e. current-1) to ensure there is no match, before placing in field.  (i.e. Do while not .nomatch  -->  create random number)